# Check for value in a JSON array using Chai/Mocha

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I have a function is js that return an JSON array

```
[
    {
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": 1,
            "lng": 2
        },
        "name": "33301 - Fort Lauderdale, Florida"
    },
    {
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": 3,
            "lng": 4
        },
        "name": "33301 - Atlanta, Georgia"
    }
]
```

How do I write a Chai expect statement to check for a name value...

Basically, I want to see if the result name parameter  contain "33301 - Atlanta, Georgia"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the data and validate:

```js
//filter your data by name
const filteredData=myObject.filter(object=>object.name==='33301 - Atlanta, Georgia');

// now you can check the length of that filtered array
expect(filteredData).to.have.length(1);
```